# Fille descriptor in this function

Tags: c, file-descriptor

I know what a descriptor file is, however I saw a des file. implemented in a function\o and I couldn't understand very well, how it works in that context.

this function is basically fetching phrases from different files and returning them.
It is working perfectly, but I would like to understand the logic of using the file_descriptor in str[].
If the file_descriptor number is let's imagine 106. It will be str[106], what is the logic of this?
thanks for all the help.

```
type here
```

```
char    *get_next_line(int file_descriptor)
{
    char        *line;
    static char *left_str[4096];

    if (file_descriptor < 0 || BUFFER_SIZE <= 0)
        return (0);
    left_str[file_descriptor] = ft_read_to_left_str(file_descriptor, left_str[file_descriptor]);
    if (!left_str[file_descriptor])
        return (NULL);
    line = ft_get_line(left_str[file_descriptor]);
    left_str[file_descriptor] = ft_new_left_str(left_str[file_descriptor]);
    return (line);
}
```

the objective is to open 3 text files and return one sentence at a time, being 1 sentence from file 1, 1 sentence from file 2, 1 sentence from file 3 etc etc etc

```
/*int   main(void)
{
    char    *line;
    int     i;
    int     filed1;
    int     filed2;
    int     filed3;
    filed1 = open("tests/test.txt", O_RDONLY);
    filed2 = open("tests/test2.txt", O_RDONLY);
    filed3 = open("tests/test3.txt", O_RDONLY);
    i = 1;
    while (i < 7)
    {
        line = get_next_line(filed1);
        printf("line [%02d]: %s", i, line);
        free(line);
        line = get_next_line(filed2);
        printf("line [%02d]: %s", i, line);
        free(line);
        line = get_next_line(filed3);
        printf("line [%02d]: %s", i, line);
        free(line);
        i++;
    }
    close(filed1);
    close(filed2);
    close(filed3);
    return (0);
}*/
```

Comment: `static char *left_str[4096];` is merely an array of 4096 pointers to `char`. `left_str[file_descriptor]` indexes into this array using `file_descriptor`, which is an integer returned from an `open` call. From this snippet, it looks like bad design, and it is unnecessary for the task of reading from three files and writing their lines interleaved to output. One could do that simply by reading a line from the first file and printing it, reading a line from the second and printing it, reading a line from the third and printing it, and repeating. There is no need for a static array.

Comment: What is `ft_read_to_left_str()`?  Post a *complete* example, please.  And unless this is homework or similar, using file descriptor-based `read()` to read *lines* is needlessly hard.  Just use standard `FILE`-based `getline()` (or `fgets()` for stuck-in-the-20th-century systems that lack `getline()` to read chunks until you get a full line).

Comment: title of your post should be a specific question to gain more traction with others who can answer it